# JQuery - Function applying only for first element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update a modal & video attributes on button click.

It works well but the problem is that it only apply this when i click on the first button ( first element with the class videoBtn ), i want it to be applied on all other buttons with the same class

here is my code

```
$(".videoBtn").click(function(){
        $("#video").attr('src',$(".videoBtn").data('src'));
        $(".modal").attr('id', $(".videoBtn").data('target').substring(1));
      });
```

Comment: This part of the code you've provided, `$(".videoBtn").click(function(){` *will* apply to all `.videoBtn` that exist at the time the code runs.  If you're adding more buttons after this code runs then you need event delegation (code in comment above).   While these parts `$(".videoBtn").data('src')` and `$("#video").attr` will always only apply to the first.  It's hard to tell from your "problem" if this is what you're experiencing.

Comment: You probably want `$("#video").attr('src',$(this).data('src'));`  (and same for other videoBtn .data("target") -> `$(this).data("target")..`

Comment: @freedomn-m Your answer is better than the first one because it contains explanations. Thanks.

Comment: @DucNguyen TBH it's hard to tell the exact issue from the description and the obvious part is the "click", so looks like the problem is "the click doesn't apply to all" - in which case event delegation is the solution.  The succinctness of the first comment is because we see a new question with that issue maybe 20-30 times *a day*.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using value of currently clicked element, but first with class, you should use `$this` instead of `$('.videoBtn')`

```js
$(".videoBtn").click(function(){
   $("#video").attr('src',$(this).data('src'));
   $(".modal").attr('id', $(this).data('target').substring(1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".videoBtn").each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $("#video").attr('src',$(".videoBtn").data('src'));
    $(".modal").attr('id', $(".videoBtn").data('target').substring(1));
  })
})
```